# Visual Studio 2010 failed tests throw exceptions

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tdd

In VisualStudio2010 Ultimate RC

I cannot figure out how to suppress

```
{"CollectionAssert.AreEqual failed. (Element at index 0 do not match.)"}
```

from

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.AssertFailedException
```

If i Ctrl+Alt+E I get the exception dialog; however that exception doesn't seem to be in there to be suppressed. Does anyone else have any experience with this? I don't remember having to suppress these Assert fails in studio 2008 when running unit tests. My tests would fail and I could just click on the TestResults to see which tests failed instead of fighting through these dialogs. For now I guess I'll just run my tests through the command window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not used VS2010 yet, but in the VS2008 exception dialog there is a button to manually add an arbitrary exception to the list. You just enter its full name (which you have quoted above), and it should remember it for you in subsequent debug sessions.